# How can I customize iCloud's "Optimize Mac Storage" function?

Tags: macbook-pro, icloud, mojave, filesystem, disk-space

iCloud has the ability to offload files from my laptop, which is useful when I am running low on space, as shown below

[image: Preferences Control panel with optimize Mac Storage selected]

In my case, I just installed Syncfusion's demos, and my files appear to be immediately "deleted and uploaded to the cloud", and it has a cloud icon., sometimes with an arrow, sometimes without

I attempt to click on the arrow, or the cloud, in the hopes of getting a configuration screen, and I get nothing.

Can someone tell me:

- How can I control this process from an iCloud perspective (Terminal, etc)
- What is the default criteria iCloud uses (Last Modified date, vs Last Access, etc.)
- Besides storing the files outside the documents directory, say at the root of my profile, is there any other option?

I'm asking because it's likely that I'll have applications that can't wait for a delay that will likely happens during a iCloud restore.  This means .NET Core assemblies, and other necessary files for development will "act weird".

Can anyone help me understand the specifics of what that "weird" will be?  E.g. the `NSFileHandler will report error code 123, until the file is restored`..  I'd like to understand the logic a little bit better.

See the bottom of this screen:
[image: Image of files being uploaded to the cloud in finder]

Comment: You've asked many questions here and I believe they've all been answered on other questions (i.e. what the cloud symbol means when you install something directly to iCloud).  Have you searched for answers provided previously?

Comment: @fsb if that's the case I'll research and consolidate them, but I'm really looking for ways to control and tune the process. I'll update

Comment: It's a bit difficult to tune other than what you've already seen iCloud Preferences.  That's about as granular as you can get.  You shouldn't install the Syncfusion demos to the iCloud folder if it will cause problems.  iCloud will sync those file across all your signed-in devices which, I think, is not what you want.